# MAX AVG score for each year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got a problem with one exercise from SQL.

"For each year, find the student with the highest average grade."

I need to get from my query informations, where there will be
osoba.imie, osoba.nazwisko, YEAR(student.datarekrutacji) AND MAX(AVG(ocena.ocena)) -
so I need to know, what was the max average OCENA.OCENA for each YEAR, and who (OSOBA.IMIE &
OSOBA.NAZWISKO) got that max.

I was trying many things, but best I could get was:

*1 situation where I have grouped YEARS with best AVG(OCENA), here is a code:

```
SELECT MAX(srednia), YEAR(datarekrutacji) 
FROM student 
INNER JOIN (SELECT idstudent, AVG(ocena) srednia FROM ocena GROUP BY idstudent) X 
ON student.idosoba = X.idstudent 
GROUP BY YEAR(datarekrutacji)
```

result_1

| średnia | rok |
| --- | --- |
| 4.500000 | 2011 |
| 4.500000 | 2012 |
| 4.000000 | 2013 |

*2 situation where I have all AVG(OCENA) with IMIE, NAZWISKO and YEAR, but the results are not
grouped in YEARS, so there is no MAX(AVG(OCENA)) for each of them, and code:

```
SELECT średnia, imie, nazwisko, YEAR(a.datarekrutacji) "Rocznik rekrutacji"
FROM student a 
INNER JOIN osoba 
ON osoba.idosoba = a.idosoba 
INNER JOIN (SELECT idstudent, AVG(ocena) średnia
FROM ocena
GROUP BY idstudent) X
ON X.idstudent = a.idosoba
```

result_2:

| średnia | imie | nazwisko | Rocznik rekrutacji |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4.333333 | Alberta | Ananas | 2011 |
| 4.500000 | Salomea | Oliwka | 2011 |
| 3.666666 | Pulchernia | Pączek | 2011 |
| 4.333333 | Gryzelda | Gruszka | 2011 |
| 3.333333 | Tymoteusz | Tymianek | 2012 |
| 4.500000 | Klara | Koperek | 2012 |
| 2.666666 | Melchior | Melon | 2012 |
| 4.000000 | Hieronim | Kapusta | 2013 |
| 4.000000 | Brunchilda | Banan | 2013 |
| 4.000000 | Salomon | Seler | 2013 |
| 3.666666 | Bonifacy | Bób | 2013 |

I should do this exercise with subquery.
Desired results are:

| średnia | imie | nazwisko | Rocznik rekrutacji |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4.500000 | Salomea | Oliwka | 2011 |
| 4.500000 | Klara | Koperek | 2012 |
| 4.000000 | Hieronim | Kapusta | 2013 |
| 4.000000 | Brunchilda | Banan | 2013 |
| 4.000000 | Salomon | Seler | 2013 |

so MAX(AVG(ocena) in each ROK, and who got that MAX(AVG(ocena).

I don't have any more ideas, so I need Your help.
Thank You :)

@edit:
MS SQL Server version - Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5 (X64)

Database schema:
[image: database_schema]

DDL code to create database:

```
-------------------------------------
--SKRYPT ZAKŁADAJĄCY SCHEMAT UCZELNIA
----------Wersja 2021-----------
--DDL MS SQL Server dla schematu UCZELNIA w wersji wyjściowej

--Rozpoczynamy tworzenie tabel
/* RokAkademicki.*/
CREATE TABLE RokAkademicki ( 
    IdRokAkademicki char(7) not null,
    Data_rozp date not null,
    Data_zak date not null)  
Go

ALTER TABLE RokAkademicki
    ADD CONSTRAINT RokAkademicki_PK PRIMARY KEY (IdRokAkademicki)   
Go

/* StudentGrupa.*/  
CREATE TABLE StudentGrupa ( 
    IdOsoba int not null,
    IdGrupa int not null)  
Go

ALTER TABLE StudentGrupa
    ADD CONSTRAINT StudentGrupa_PK PRIMARY KEY (IdGrupa, IdOsoba)   
Go

/* Grupa.*/  
CREATE TABLE Grupa (
    IdGrupa Int Identity not null,
    NrGrupy char(10) not null,
    SemestrNauki int not null,
    IdRokAkademicki char(7) not null)  
Go

ALTER TABLE Grupa
    ADD CONSTRAINT Grupa_PK PRIMARY KEY (IdGrupa)   
Go

/* PrzedmiotPoprzedzajacy.*/  
CREATE TABLE PrzedmiotPoprzedzajacy ( 
    IdPoprzednik int not null,
    IdPrzedmiot int not null)  
Go

ALTER TABLE PrzedmiotPoprzedzajacy
    ADD CONSTRAINT PrzedmiotPoprzedzajacy_PK PRIMARY KEY (IdPoprzednik, IdPrzedmiot)   
Go

/* Przedmiot.*/  
CREATE TABLE Przedmiot ( 
    IdPrzedmiot int identity not null,
    Przedmiot varchar(128) not null,
    Symbol char(3) not null
    --,IdKatedra int null
    )  
Go

ALTER TABLE Przedmiot
    ADD CONSTRAINT Przedmiot_PK PRIMARY KEY (IdPrzedmiot)   
Go

/* StopnieTytuly.*/  
CREATE TABLE StopnieTytuly ( 
    IdStopien int identity not null,
    Stopien varchar(32) not null,
    Skrot varchar(10) not null)  
Go

ALTER TABLE StopnieTytuly
    ADD CONSTRAINT StopnieTytuly_PK PRIMARY KEY (IdStopien)   
Go

/* Ocena.*/  
CREATE TABLE Ocena ( 
    IdStudent int not null,
    IdPrzedmiot int not null,
    DataWystawienia date not null,
    IdDydaktyk int not null,
    Ocena decimal(2,1) not null)
Go

ALTER TABLE Ocena
    ADD CONSTRAINT Ocena_PK PRIMARY KEY (IdStudent, DataWystawienia, IdPrzedmiot)   
Go

/* Panstwo.*/  
CREATE TABLE Panstwo ( 
    IdPanstwo int identity not null,
    Panstwo varchar(64) not null)  
Go

ALTER TABLE Panstwo
    ADD CONSTRAINT Panstwo_PK PRIMARY KEY (IdPanstwo)   
Go

/* Osoba.*/  
CREATE TABLE Osoba ( 
    IdOsoba int identity not null,
    Nazwisko varchar(62) not null,
    Imie varchar(32) not null,
    DataUrodzenia date null
    )  
Go

ALTER TABLE Osoba
    ADD CONSTRAINT Osoba_PK PRIMARY KEY (IdOsoba)   
Go

/* Student.*/  
CREATE TABLE Student ( 
    IdOsoba int not null,
    NrIndeksu char(10) not null,
    DataRekrutacji date not null)  
Go

ALTER TABLE Student
    ADD CONSTRAINT Student_PK PRIMARY KEY (IdOsoba)   
Go

/* Dydaktyk.*/  
CREATE TABLE Dydaktyk ( 
    IdOsoba int not null
    ,IdStopien int null
    ,Podlega int null
    )  
Go

ALTER TABLE Dydaktyk
    ADD CONSTRAINT Dydaktyk_PK PRIMARY KEY (IdOsoba)   
Go

/* Add foreign key constraints to table StudentGrupa.*/
ALTER TABLE StudentGrupa
    ADD CONSTRAINT Student_StudentGrupa_FK1 foreign key (IdOsoba)
     references Student (IdOsoba) on update no action on delete no action  
Go

ALTER TABLE StudentGrupa
    ADD CONSTRAINT Grupa_StudentGrupa_FK1 foreign key (IdGrupa)
     references Grupa (IdGrupa) on update no action on delete no action  
Go

/* Add foreign key constraints to table Grupa.*/
ALTER TABLE Grupa
    ADD CONSTRAINT RokAkad_GrupaStud_FK1 foreign key (IdRokAkademicki)
     references RokAkademicki (IdRokAkademicki) on update no action on delete no action  
Go

ALTER TABLE Grupa
    ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_Rok_Nr UNIQUE (NrGrupy, IdRokAkademicki)
Go

/* Add foreign key constraints to table PrzedmiotPoprzedzajacy.*/
ALTER TABLE PrzedmiotPoprzedzajacy
    ADD CONSTRAINT Przedmiot_PrzedmiotPop_FK1 foreign key (IdPoprzednik)
     references Przedmiot (IdPrzedmiot) on update no action on delete no action  
Go

ALTER TABLE PrzedmiotPoprzedzajacy
    ADD CONSTRAINT Przedmiot_PrzedmiotPop_FK2 foreign key (IdPrzedmiot)
     references Przedmiot (IdPrzedmiot) on update no action on delete no action  
Go

/* Add foreign key constraints to table Ocena.*/
ALTER TABLE Ocena
    ADD CONSTRAINT Dydaktyk_Ocena_FK1 foreign key (IdDydaktyk)
     references Dydaktyk (IdOsoba) on update no action on delete no action  
Go

ALTER TABLE Ocena
    ADD CONSTRAINT Student_Ocena_FK1 foreign key (IdStudent)
     references Student (IdOsoba) on update no action on delete no action  
Go

ALTER TABLE Ocena
    ADD CONSTRAINT Przedmiot_Ocena_FK1 foreign key (IdPrzedmiot)
     references Przedmiot (IdPrzedmiot) on update no action on delete no action  
Go

/* Add foreign key constraints to table Student.*/
ALTER TABLE Student
    ADD CONSTRAINT Osoba_Student_FK1 foreign key (IdOsoba)
     references Osoba (IdOsoba) on update no action on delete no action  
Go

/* Add foreign key constraints to table Dydaktyk.*/
ALTER TABLE Dydaktyk
    ADD CONSTRAINT Osoba_Dydaktyk_FK1 foreign key (IdOsoba)
     references Osoba (IdOsoba) on update no action on delete no action  
Go

ALTER TABLE Dydaktyk
    ADD CONSTRAINT StopnieTytuly_Dydaktyk_FK1 foreign key (IdStopien)
     references StopnieTytuly (IdStopien) on update no action on delete no action  
Go

ALTER TABLE Dydaktyk
    ADD CONSTRAINT Dydaktyk_Dydaktyk_FK1 foreign key (Podlega)
     references Dydaktyk (IdOsoba) on update no action on delete no action  
Go

/* This is the end of the Microsoft Visual Studio generated SQL DDL script.*/
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INSERT INTO RokAkademicki (IdRokAkademicki, Data_rozp, Data_zak)
VALUES  ('2011_12', '2011-10-01', '2012-08-31'),
        ('2012_13', '2012-10-01', '2013-08-31'),
        ('2013_14', '2013-10-01', '2014-08-31'),
        ('2014_15', '2014-10-01', '2015-08-31');
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INSERT INTO Grupa (NrGrupy, SemestrNauki, IdRokAkademicki)
VALUES  ('WIs I.1', 1, '2011_12'),
        ('WIs I.2', 1, '2011_12'),
        ('WIs II.1', 2, '2011_12'),
        ('WIs II.2', 2, '2011_12'),

        ('WIs I.1', 1, '2012_13'),
        ('WIs I.2', 1, '2012_13'),
        ('WIs II.1', 2, '2012_13'),
        ('WIs II.2', 2, '2012_13'),
        ('WIs III.1', 3, '2012_13'),
        ('WIs III.2', 3, '2012_13'),
        ('WIs IV.1', 4, '2012_13'),
        ('WIs IV.2', 4, '2012_13'),

        ('WIs I.1', 1, '2013_14'),
        ('WIs I.2', 1, '2013_14'),
        ('WIs II.1', 2, '2013_14'),
        ('WIs II.2', 2, '2013_14'),
        ('WIs III.1', 3, '2013_14'),
        ('WIs III.2', 3, '2013_14'),
        ('WIs IV.1', 4, '2013_14'),
        ('WIs IV.2', 4, '2013_14'),
        ('WIs V.1', 5, '2013_14'),
        ('WIs VI.1', 6, '2013_14'),

        ('WIs I.1', 1, '2014_15'),
        ('WIs I.2', 1, '2014_15'),
        ('WIs II.1', 2, '2014_15'),
        ('WIs II.2', 2, '2014_15');
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SET Identity_insert Przedmiot ON 
Go

INSERT INTO Przedmiot (IdPrzedmiot, Przedmiot, Symbol)
VALUES  (1,'Systemy baz danych', 'SBD'),
        (2,'Relacyjne bazy danych', 'RBD'),
        (3,'Algebra liniowa i geometria', 'ALG'),
        (4,'Matematyka dyskretna', 'MAD'),
        (5,'Systemy operacyjne', 'SOP'),
        (6,'Analiza matematyczna I', 'AM1'),
        (7,'Inżynieria oprogramowania', 'INO'),
        (8,'Projektowanie baz danych', 'BDA'),
        (9,'Administrowanie bazą danych', 'ADM'),
        (10,'Analiza matematyczna II', 'AM2'),
        (11,'Algorytmy i struktury danych', 'ASD'),
        (12,'Administracja systemów operacyjnych', 'ASO');
SET Identity_insert Przedmiot OFF
Go
INSERT INTO PrzedmiotPoprzedzajacy (IdPoprzednik, IdPrzedmiot)
VALUES (2,1),(3,4), (6, 10), (4, 11), (5,12);
go
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SET Identity_insert StopnieTytuly ON 
Go

alter table Stopnietytuly alter column skrot varchar(16)
INSERT INTO StopnieTytuly (IdStopien, Skrot, Stopien)
VALUES  (1, 'Prof. Dr hab.', 'Profesor Doktor habilitowany')
        ,(2, 'Dr hab.', 'Doktor habilitowany')
        ,(3, 'Dr', 'Doktor')
        ,(4, 'Mgr', 'Magister')
        ,(5, 'Inż', 'Inżynier');

SET Identity_insert StopnieTytuly OFF
Go
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SET Identity_insert Panstwo ON 
Go

INSERT INTO Panstwo (IdPanstwo, Panstwo)
VALUES (14, 'Białoruś'),
        (4, 'Czechy'),
        (15, 'Francja'),
        (10, 'Niemcy'),
        (3, 'Polska'),
        (12, 'Rosja'),
        (18, 'Rumunia'),
        (11, 'Słowacja'),
        (16, 'Słowenia'),
        (13, 'Ukraina'),
        (2, 'USA'),
        (19,'Hiszpania'),
        (23,'Turcja'),
        (21,'Finlandia'),
        (22,'Wlochy'),
        (24, 'Grecja');

SET Identity_insert Panstwo OFF
Go

--Dydaktycy------------------------
SET Identity_insert osoba ON 
Go

INSERT INTO osoba
(IdOsoba,
 Imie,
 Nazwisko,
 DataUrodzenia
)
VALUES
(1,
 'Apolinary',
 'Anyżek',
'1960-12-01'
);
Go
INSERT  INTO Dydaktyk (IdOsoba, IdStopien)
VALUES  (1 ,1);
Go
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INSERT INTO osoba
(IdOsoba,
 Imie,
 Nazwisko,
 DataUrodzenia
)
VALUES (2, 'Balbina', 'Bakłażan', '1991-02-03');
go
INSERT  INTO Dydaktyk (IdOsoba, IdStopien)
VALUES  (2,4);
go
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INSERT INTO osoba
(IdOsoba,
 Imie,
 Nazwisko,
 DataUrodzenia
)
VALUES (3, 'Baltazar', 'Bigos','1995-09-04');
go
INSERT  INTO Dydaktyk (IdOsoba, IdStopien)
VALUES  (3,5);
go

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INSERT INTO osoba
(IdOsoba,
 Imie,
 Nazwisko,
 DataUrodzenia
)
VALUES (4, 'Cezary', 'Czosnek', '1958-11-11');
go
INSERT  INTO Dydaktyk (IdOsoba, IdStopien)
VALUES  (4, 1);
go
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INSERT INTO osoba
(IdOsoba,
 Imie,
 Nazwisko,
 DataUrodzenia
)
VALUES (5, 'Domicella', 'Dynia', '1982-06-30');
go
INSERT  INTO Dydaktyk (IdOsoba, IdStopien)
VALUES  (5 ,3);

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INSERT INTO osoba
(IdOsoba,
 Imie,
 Nazwisko,
 DataUrodzenia
)
VALUES (6, 'Bazyli', 'Brokuł', '1971-03-08');
go
INSERT  INTO Dydaktyk (IdOsoba, IdStopien)
VALUES  (6,2);
go
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INSERT INTO osoba
(IdOsoba,
 Imie,
 Nazwisko,
 DataUrodzenia
)
VALUES (7, 'Kajetan', 'Kalafior', '1989-05-03');
go
INSERT  INTO Dydaktyk (IdOsoba, IdStopien)
VALUES  (7,4);

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INSERT INTO osoba
(IdOsoba,
 Imie,
 Nazwisko,
 DataUrodzenia
)
VALUES (8, 'Kunegunda', 'Karp', '1995-10-21');
go
INSERT  INTO Dydaktyk (IdOsoba, IdStopien)
VALUES  (8,5);
go
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INSERT INTO osoba
(IdOsoba,
 Imie,
 Nazwisko,
 DataUrodzenia
)
VALUES (9, 'January', 'Jajecznica', '1965-05-22');
go
INSERT  INTO Dydaktyk (IdOsoba, IdStopien)
VALUES  (9,2);
go
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INSERT INTO osoba
(IdOsoba,
 Imie,
 Nazwisko,
 DataUrodzenia
)
VALUES (10, 'Archibald', 'Agrest', '1978-09-05');
go  
INSERT  INTO Dydaktyk (IdOsoba, IdStopien)
VALUES  (10,3);
go
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INSERT INTO osoba
(IdOsoba,
 Imie,
 Nazwisko,
 DataUrodzenia
)
VALUES (11, 'Kleofas', 'Klops', '1977-11-11');
go
INSERT  INTO Dydaktyk (IdOsoba, IdStopien)
VALUES  (11, 4);
go
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INSERT INTO osoba
(IdOsoba,
 Imie,
 Nazwisko
)
VALUES (23, 'Winicjusz', 'Wężymord');
go
INSERT  INTO Dydaktyk (IdOsoba, IdStopien)
VALUES  (23, NULL);
go
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
UPDATE Dydaktyk SET Podlega = 1 WHERE IdOsoba IN (6,10,2,3);
UPDATE Dydaktyk SET Podlega = 4 WHERE IdOsoba IN (5, 9)
UPDATE Dydaktyk SET Podlega = 9 WHERE IdOsoba IN (7, 11);
UPDATE Dydaktyk SET Podlega = 5 WHERE IdOsoba IN (8, 23);
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--Studenci
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INSERT  INTO osoba (IdOsoba, Imie, Nazwisko, DataUrodzenia) VALUES (12,'Alberta', 'Ananas', '1991-03-05');
go
INSERT  INTO Student (IdOsoba, DataRekrutacji, NrIndeksu)   
VALUES  (12, '2011-09-12','s2121');
INSERT  INTO Dydaktyk (IdOsoba, IdStopien)
VALUES  (12, 5);
go
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INSERT  INTO osoba (IdOsoba, Imie, Nazwisko, DataUrodzenia) VALUES (13, 'Salomea', 'Œliwka', '1992-05-15');
go
INSERT  INTO Student (IdOsoba, DataRekrutacji, NrIndeksu)
VALUES  (13, '2011-09-13','s2126');
go
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INSERT  INTO osoba (IdOsoba, Imie, Nazwisko, DataUrodzenia) VALUES (14, 'Pulchernia', 'Pączek', '1993-08-14');
go
INSERT  INTO Student (IdOsoba, DataRekrutacji, NrIndeksu)
VALUES  (14, '2011-08-19','s2101');
go
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INSERT  INTO osoba (IdOsoba, Imie, Nazwisko, DataUrodzenia) VALUES (15, 'Gryzelda', 'Gruszka', '1990-12-24');
go
INSERT  INTO Student (IdOsoba, DataRekrutacji, NrIndeksu)
VALUES  (15, '2011-10-01','s2135');
go
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INSERT  INTO osoba (IdOsoba, Imie, Nazwisko, DataUrodzenia) VALUES (16, 'Tymoteusz', 'Tymianek', '1993-11-21');
go
INSERT  INTO Student (IdOsoba, DataRekrutacji, NrIndeksu)
VALUES  (16, '2012-08-12','s3162');
go
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INSERT  INTO osoba (IdOsoba, Imie, Nazwisko, DataUrodzenia) VALUES (17, 'Klara', 'Koperek', '1994-03-22');
go
INSERT  INTO Student (IdOsoba, DataRekrutacji, NrIndeksu)
VALUES  (17, '2012-09-23','s3177');
go
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INSERT  INTO osoba (IdOsoba, Imie, Nazwisko, DataUrodzenia) VALUES (18, 'Melchior', 'Melon', '1995-08-09');
go
INSERT  INTO Student (IdOsoba, DataRekrutacji, NrIndeksu)
VALUES  (18, '2012-07-22','s3045');
go
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INSERT  INTO osoba (IdOsoba, Imie, Nazwisko, DataUrodzenia) VALUES (19, 'Hieronim', 'Kapusta', '1994-08-09');
go
INSERT  INTO Student (IdOsoba, DataRekrutacji, NrIndeksu)
VALUES  (19, '2013-08-05','s4120');
go
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INSERT  INTO osoba (IdOsoba, Imie, Nazwisko, DataUrodzenia) VALUES (20, 'Brunchilda', 'Banan', '1995-07-07');
go
INSERT  INTO Student (IdOsoba, DataRekrutacji, NrIndeksu)
VALUES  (20, '2013-07-16','s4022');
go
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INSERT  INTO osoba (IdOsoba, Imie, Nazwisko, DataUrodzenia) VALUES (21, 'Salomon', 'Seler', '1994-11-05');
go
INSERT  INTO Student (IdOsoba, DataRekrutacji, NrIndeksu)
VALUES  (21, '2013-07-06','s4004');
go
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INSERT  INTO osoba (IdOsoba, Imie, Nazwisko, DataUrodzenia) VALUES (22, 'Bonifacy', 'Bób', '1996-03-09');
go
INSERT  INTO Student (IdOsoba, DataRekrutacji, NrIndeksu)
VALUES  (22, '2013-09-22','s4321');
go
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INSERT  INTO osoba (IdOsoba, Imie, Nazwisko, DataUrodzenia) VALUES (24, 'Pafnucy', 'Papryka', '1997-02-19');
go
INSERT  INTO Student (IdOsoba, DataRekrutacji, NrIndeksu)
VALUES  (24, '2013-09-22','s4322');
go
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INSERT  INTO osoba (IdOsoba, Imie, Nazwisko, DataUrodzenia) VALUES (25, 'Pankracy', 'Por', '1995-07-09');
go
INSERT  INTO Student (IdOsoba, DataRekrutacji, NrIndeksu)
VALUES  (25, '2013-09-22','s4323');
go
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INSERT INTO Osoba (IdOsoba, Imie, Nazwisko, DataUrodzenia)
VALUES (26, 'Cecylia', 'Cebula', '1997-12-02');
Go
INSERT INTO Student (Idosoba, NrIndeksu, DataRekrutacji)
VALUES (26, 5122, '2014-06-11');
Go
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INSERT INTO Osoba (IdOsoba, Imie, Nazwisko, DataUrodzenia)
VALUES (27, 'Dezydery', 'Dąb', '1998-01-22');
Go
INSERT INTO Student (Idosoba, NrIndeksu, DataRekrutacji)
VALUES (27, 5131, '2014-07-17');
Go
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INSERT INTO Osoba (IdOsoba, Imie, Nazwisko, DataUrodzenia)
VALUES (28, 'Konstancja', 'Koperek', '1996-02-02');
Go
INSERT INTO Student (Idosoba, NrIndeksu, DataRekrutacji)
VALUES (28, 5138, '2014-07-22');
Go
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INSERT INTO Osoba (IdOsoba, Imie, Nazwisko, DataUrodzenia)
VALUES (29, 'Judyta', 'Jarmuż', '1997-08-28');
Go
INSERT INTO Student (Idosoba, NrIndeksu, DataRekrutacji)
VALUES (29, 5141, '2014-08-12');
Go
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INSERT INTO Osoba (IdOsoba, Imie, Nazwisko, DataUrodzenia)
VALUES (30, 'Klaudiusz', 'Karczoch', '1996-09-06');
Go
INSERT INTO Student (Idosoba, NrIndeksu, DataRekrutacji)
VALUES (30, 5144, '2014-08-22');
Go
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INSERT INTO Osoba (IdOsoba, Imie, Nazwisko, DataUrodzenia)
VALUES (31, 'Sykstus', 'Szczaw', '1997-10-05');
Go
INSERT INTO Student (Idosoba, NrIndeksu, DataRekrutacji)
VALUES (31, 5149, '2014-09-01');
Go
SET Identity_insert osoba OFF
Go
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------Studenci w grupach----------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INSERT INTO StudentGrupa (IdOsoba, IdGrupa)
VALUES (12, 1), (12, 3), (12,9), (12, 11), (12,21), (12, 22), (13, 1), (13, 3), (13,9), (13, 11), (13,21), (13, 22),
        (14, 1), (14, 3), (14,9), (14, 11), (14,21), (14, 22), (15, 1), (15, 3), (15,9), (15, 11), (15,21), (15, 22),
        (16, 5), (17, 5), (18, 5), (16, 7), (17, 7), (18, 7),(16, 17), (17, 17), (18, 17), (16, 19), (17, 19), (18, 19),
        (19,13), (20,13), (21,13), (22, 14), (24, 14), (25,14), (19,15), (20, 15), (21,15), (22, 16), (24, 16), (25, 16), 
        (26, 23), (27,23), (28, 23), (29, 24), (30, 24),(31, 24), (26, 25), (27, 25), (28, 25), (29, 26),(30, 26), (31, 26);
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------Oceny-------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
INSERT  INTO Ocena (IdStudent, IdPrzedmiot, DataWystawienia, Ocena, IdDydaktyk)
VALUES (12, 6, '2012-01-20', 4.0, 1),
        (13, 6, '2012-01-20', 4.5, 1),
        (14, 6, '2012-01-20', 3.0, 1),
        (15, 6, '2012-01-20', 5.0, 1),

        (16, 6, '2013-01-25', 2.0, 1),
        (17, 6, '2013-01-25', 4.5, 1),
        (18, 6, '2013-01-25', 3.0, 1),
        (16, 6, '2013-02-02', 3.0, 1),

        (19, 6, '2014-01-18', 5.0, 1),
        (20, 6, '2014-01-18', 4.0, 1),
        (21, 6, '2014-01-18', 4.5, 1),
        (22, 6, '2014-01-18', 2.0, 1),
        (22, 6, '2014-01-30', 4.0, 1),

        (12, 2, '2012-01-22', 5.0, 9),
        (13, 2, '2012-01-22', 4.5, 9),
        (14, 2, '2012-01-22', 4.0, 9),
        (15, 2, '2012-01-22', 5.0, 9),

        (16, 2, '2013-01-23', 5.0, 9),
        (17, 2, '2013-01-23', 4.5, 9),
        (18, 2, '2013-01-23', 2.0, 9),
        (18, 2, '2013-02-01', 3.0, 9),

        (19, 2, '2014-01-18', 3.0, 9),
        (20, 2, '2014-01-18', 4.0, 9),
        (21, 2, '2014-01-18', 3.5, 9),
        (22, 2, '2014-01-18', 5.0, 9),

        (12, 12, '2014-01-18', 4.0, 8),
        (13, 12, '2014-01-18', 4.5, 8),
        (14, 12, '2014-01-18', 4.0, 8),
        (15, 12, '2014-01-18', 3.0, 8);
```

Comment: Please do not post image. Use formatted text instead

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question, no images.

Comment: Siema! (I must admit, having tables and attributes in Polish may make others have difficulty understanding what even "grade" is in Polish ;) ). Anyway, Result_2 was really close! I take it you are learning about SQL, so I would suggest looking up what `WITH` can do. It could help you to "save" the result_2-query and then `SELECT` from that query. At that point, you can take the highest of all students for a particular year. (Using `MAX`, and grouping it by year (`GROUP BY rocznik`). Give it a try, and if you can't get it to fully work, post it here and I'll adjust it and make an answer of it.

Comment: Thank You guys, I have already edited my post :)

I was also trying to solve this with "WITH", but I still can't group my results in YEARS, with names of students, that got the MAX(AVG(ocena))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table ocena shows the grades. It contains the student ID and a date. You want to find the average grade per student and year. This is:

```
SELECT
  YEAR(datawystawienia) AS year,
  idstudent,
  AVG(ocena) AS avg_grade
FROM ocena
GROUP BY YEAR(datawystawienia), idstudent;
```

You can use this to get the top student(s) per year. The easiest approach to this is probably using a window function (`MAX OVER` in below query):

```
SELECT year, idstudent, avg_grade
FROM
(
  SELECT
    YEAR(datawystawienia) AS year,
    idstudent,
    AVG(ocena) AS avg_grade,
    MAX(AVG(ocena)) OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(datawystawienia)) AS max_avg_grade
  FROM ocena
  GROUP BY YEAR(datawystawienia), idstudent
) aggregated
WHERE avg_grade = max_avg_grade
ORDER BY year, idstudent;
```

And you can of course join the student data (osoba) to this result.

Answer (score 0):

Thank You Thorsten Kettner for your solution.
I forgot to mention, that I need to group results by YEAR of student.datarekrutacji not by YEAR of ocena.datawystawienia, but your post really helped me. I changed the code to match my requirements, and finally it looks like that:

```
SELECT year, imie, nazwisko, avg_grade
FROM (SELECT YEAR(datarekrutacji) AS year, idstudent, AVG(ocena) AS avg_grade,
        MAX(AVG(ocena)) OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(datarekrutacji)) AS max_avg_grade
        FROM ocena
        INNER JOIN student
        ON ocena.idstudent = student.idosoba
        GROUP BY YEAR(datarekrutacji), idstudent) aggregated,
        osoba, student
WHERE avg_grade = max_avg_grade
AND osoba.idosoba = student.idosoba
AND aggregated.idstudent = student.idosoba;
```

The result is:

| year | imie | nazwisko | avg_grade |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2011 | Salomea | Oliwka | 4.500000 |
| 2012 | Klara | Koperek | 4.500000 |
| 2013 | Hieronim | Kapusta | 4.000000 |
| 2013 | Brunchilda | Banan | 4.000000 |
| 2013 | Salomon | Seler | 4.000000 |

But during changing your code, I got an idea and tried to connect my 2 previous codes.
And finally I created that monster :D (I don't know if it is all correct, but the results are):

```
SELECT YEAR(datarekrutacji) rok, imie, nazwisko, AVG(ocena) ocena
FROM student
INNER JOIN osoba
ON student.idosoba = osoba.idosoba
INNER JOIN ocena
ON ocena.idstudent = osoba.idosoba

GROUP BY YEAR(datarekrutacji), imie, nazwisko

HAVING YEAR(datarekrutacji) IN (SELECT YEAR(datarekrutacji)
                                FROM student 
                                INNER JOIN (SELECT idstudent, AVG(ocena) srednia FROM ocena GROUP BY idstudent) X 
                                ON student.idosoba = X.idstudent 
                                GROUP BY YEAR(datarekrutacji))

AND AVG(ocena) IN               (SELECT MAX(srednia)
                                FROM student 
                                INNER JOIN (SELECT idstudent, AVG(ocena) srednia FROM ocena GROUP BY idstudent) X 
                                ON student.idosoba = X.idstudent 
                                GROUP BY YEAR(datarekrutacji))
```

Result of query:

| rok | imie | nazwisko | ocena |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2011 | Salomea | Oliwka | 4.500000 |
| 2012 | Klara | Koperek | 4.500000 |
| 2013 | Brunchilda | Banan | 4.000000 |
| 2013 | Hieronim | Kapusta | 4.000000 |
| 2013 | Salomon | Seler | 4.000000 |

Comment: The second query doesn't look correct. `HAVING YEAR(datarekrutacji) IN` guarantees the year to be one of the staudent's years, which is true for all years. `AND AVG(ocena) IN` guarantees the value to be the top in some year, but not necessarily in the year you want it to be. It would have to be `HAVING (YEAR(datarekrutacji), AVG(ocena)) IN (...)`, but SQL Server does not support this syntax. You could use `HAVING EXISTS (...)` instead. But, well, it's simpler to use `MAX OVER` or at least use a `WITH` clause.